# How do you bundle a React app to be consumed by a legacy web app that doesn't use a bundler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, esbuild

I have a legacy MVC app that I would like to add React components to piece-meal. The MVC app runs without any bundler and just old-school script includes, however we only support the latest browsers.

If I write bare React components and use Babel I can easily include the components into any existing page by running the babel transpile:

```
babel --presets @babel/preset-react --watch <react file directory> -d <browser JS directory>
```

And then providing a factory that creates a React app on my page for a component:

```
import OrgTree from ./OrgTree.js

function OrgTreeFactory (elementId) {
   ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(elementId)).render(
    <OrgTree />);
}

export default OrgTreeFactory;
```

Of course, this only works by including the browser version of the React library JS files somewhere. As soon as I need a UI library, then this no longer works. For instance, the bare imports fail when I install the devextreme react UI components and try to use them:

```
import 'devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css'
import { TreeList, Paging, Scrolling, RemoteOperations, Column } from 'devextreme-react/tree-list'
```

So now I have to figure out a way to bundle everything such that the signatures of my factory functions are preserved, but all of the stuff beneath it is bundled and minified such that it can be used by the browser. Ideally I want to use ESM exports at the root level so that my old-school vanilla JS files can do this:

```
<script>
import MyReactComponent from /Content/MyReactLib.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    MyReactComponent (<some element id>);
});
</script>
```

I've tried a few things:

- Just using Rollup without minification may work, but the library is huge, so minifying would be good.
- I've also used Vite to create a bundle, however that bundle is minified so that any Factory functions within the JS files are obscured.
- I've tried running Vite in library mode, but that exports files that are meant to be consumed by NodeJS, not the browser.
- I'm now digging into the esbuild options within Vite to see if I can specify what files to preserve signatures for.

Does anyone have a good idea of how to make a React library like this consumable by legacy JS without requiring a bundler to be used for all your JS?

Comment: "*bundle is minified so that any Factory functions within the JS files are obscured.*" - they shouldn't, if they are declared as global entrypoints

Comment: Any chance to convert your MVC app to use ES modules, then use a modern bundling process on it? Does the existing code have any proper structure, or is it globals over and over?

Comment: @Bergi - no matter what entrypoint I declare in the Vite config, everything will be minified as a single page such that it can't be used by anything external with the original names.

Comment: @Bergi - I can use ESM modules in the browser. But I'm not mixing in node_modules and bundling at the root of the MVC project, because that would mix all the new and old stuff together and everything else is built with regular script/css includes. I don't think that will work well.

Comment: Ah I guess I didn't mean an "entrypoint module", but the module entrypoints as defined by the [`build.lib` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib) when [building in library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) so that the bundle will keep the original names of globals to be used externally.

Comment: Re "*everything else is built with regular script includes*" - can you change *those* to modules, as the first step in your refactoring?

Comment: @Bergi - Library mode does seem to work once I use the replace plugin to remove the process.env.NODE_ENV strings. But now I'm having issues with the CSS having \" and \n.

And I'm not refactoring, I'm adding modern components to an old app.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the magic sauce. This method should apply to anyone looking to incorporate a modern UI into their existing app using Vite as a bundler.

This was the procedure:

1. Setup Vite for React following the instructions (https://vitejs.dev/guide/)
2. Install the following plugins:

   ```
   @rollup/plugin-replace  
   vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js
   ```
3. Build Vite in Library mode while using the Replace and CSS injection plugins. The config for that looks like this:

   ```
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'  
   import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'  
   import { resolve } from 'path'  
   import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'  
   import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js'  

   // https://vitejs.dev/config/  
   export default defineConfig({   
       build: {  
           lib: {  
               entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib.js'),  
               name: 'lib',  
               fileName: 'lib',  
               formats: ['es'],  
           },  
           sourcemap: true,  
           minify: false  
       },  
       plugins: [  
           cssInjectedByJsPlugin(),  
           react(),  
           replace({  
               preventAssignment: true,  
               'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),  
           }),  
       ]  
   })
   ```
4. Create factories for all your React top-level components that create a React app for the component inside some element.

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
   import SomeComponent from './react-components/SomeComponent.jsx'

   function SomeComponentFactory (elementId) {
       ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(elementId)).render(
           <React.StrictMode>
             <SomeComponent />
           </React.StrictMode>,
       );
   }

   export default SomeComponentFactory;
   ```
5. Create a file for your library in the src directory called lib.js and import/export all your factories.

   ```
   import SomeComponentFactory from './SomeComponentFactory.jsx';  
   export {SomeComponentFactory}
   ```

Then any vanilla JS component can just reference the dist/lib.js and call one of the factories to instantiate the component. This build is, obviously, for dev since the minification is off and the source-map on.